# Find by use of differentials the approximate total area of a right circular cone whose base radius and height are 5.03 inches and 11.89 inches.

Tags: calculus, differential

Find by use of differentials the approximate total area of a right circular cone whose base radius
and height are $5.03$ inches and $11.89$ inches, respectively.

I know I have to find the total derivative of the surface area of the cone, but how can I find $dr/dt$ and $dh/dt$? Or do I have to?

Comment: Use the fact that $$ A(5.03,11.89)-A(5,12)\approx A_r(5,12)\cdot 0.03 +A_h(5,12)\cdot -0.11$$ where $A(r,h)=\pi r^2+\pi \sqrt{r^2+h^2}$

Comment: Thank you for that fact, Matthew H.

Comment: Please do not use tags you do not understand. This is basic calculus, nothing to do with differential geometry.